# Finding the local extrema for a curve of intersection of two surfaces and Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: maxima-minima, curves, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose that I'm trying to find a local extrema for $f\left(x,y\right)$ subject to the constraint $g\left(x,y\right)=c$, is this equivalent to finding the local extrema for the curve of intesection of the surfaces $f\left(x,y\right)$ & $h\left(x,y\right)=g\left(x,y\right)-c$?

To elaborate further, suppose that we're trying to locate an extrema for $f\left(x,y\right)=x^2y$ subject to $x^2+y^2=1$ is locating this equivalent to locating an extrema for the curve of intersections of the two surfaces $f\left(x,y\right)=x^2y$ & $h\left(x,y\right)=x^2+y^2-1$

Comment: What is meant by the "surfaces $f(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$" and the "intersection" of those?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear :)

Comment: $f(x,y) = x^2y$ is not a surface. Similarly $h(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1$ is not a surface either. For example, the solution set to $h(x,y) = 4$ is surface.

Comment: I think that $f\left(x,y\right)$ and $h\left(x,y\right)$ are surfaces and when we set $f\left(x,y\right)=4$ we get a curve.

Comment: But how can a constraint conceptually be a constant ? and be not a variable? The constraint function should have no $=$ sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a 2D problem, not a 3D problem.

The task is to find the relative extrema of the function $f(x,y)=x^2y$ on the circle in the $xy$-plane whose equation is $x^2+y^2=1$.

The method of Lagrange multipliers will work, but isn't really needed here.

Given the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$, we can write $f(x,y)=(1-y^2)y$, which reduces the problem to that of finding the relative extrema of the function $g(y)=(1-y^2)y$ for $y\in [-1,1]$.

Can you finish it?

As regards your attempt to interpret the problem in 3D, note that in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the graph of the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ is a cylinder, which is not the same as the graph of the equation $z=x^2+y^2-1$ which is a paraboloid.

A correct 3D interpretation could be stated as:

Find the points $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ on the curve of intersection of the surfaces with equations given by
\begin{align*}
&A:&&z=x^2y\\[4pt]
&B:&&x^2+y^2=1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
such that $z$ assumes a relative extreme value.

However the above 3D interpretation doesn't make the problem easier to solve.

Comment: That was really helpful thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

We take $(x,y)$ to represent scalars, segment lengths as traditional and *not coordinates* of a surface.

Lets say we need to maximize volume $V =x^2 y$ of a brick of square section breadth and height x and length y subject to condition  that extremities stay on unit cylinder:

$$ x^2+y^2= 1 \tag1 $$

To find optimum solution by application of Lagrange Multiplier

$$ \dfrac{2 x y}{x^2}=\dfrac{2x}{2y}\rightarrow 2 y^2= x^2$$

$$y=\pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2} \tag2x$$
is a pair of planes intersecting the given unit cylinder.

Solving (1) and (2)

$$ x=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}},\, y=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}};\,$$

This realizes a maximum volume ( that calculates to $\dfrac{16 \sqrt3}{9} )\;$ 3D brick in a rough hand-sketch:

[image]

Comment: I think that $y=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}};\,$ is for both $x=+\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}};\,$ & $x=-\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}};\,$